# Editing/Creating a Triangular Solder Bridge Footprint

Tags: pcb-design, kicad

[image]

I wish to use a triangular solder jumper (solder-jumper) in my PCB and I am using KiCAD. The only available solder jumper - the one pointing in one direction (as in the attached image), is 2.45 x 1.50 mm. I wish to edit this and make it 1.25 x 1.25 mm.

Issue is I am unable to change the dimensions of the footprint in the footprint editor ( I have a copy which I am editing not the main one ) nor am I able to create an entirely new one as whenever you change the dimensions in the edit dialog box, the size remains the same. The Triangular Cu area seems specifically edited in some way.

Is it possible to make a custom F.Cu shape like the one used for the Solder Jumper Triangular in KiCAD ? If yes, how to do it ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such footprints are made out of a graphic shape (a polygon) and merged with a pad to provide the track anchor point.

How to change?  select the pad you want to modify and right click to view the "explode pad" option

[image]

Now you will be able to see a small SMT pad and the polygon. The SMT is where KiCAD will track to.
[image]

Resize the polygon to your desired shape
[image]

Finally right-click on the polygon and select "Create pad from selected shapes"

This should be easier in V6 as there is direct poly to copper flood

Answer (score -2):

Don’t use solder bridges. They are literally made of a spacing violation and can’t be counted on to be manufacturable. Further, to change them you have to change the pastemask. Use zero-ohm jumpers instead: reliable, cheap, and only the BOM changes to change the strap.

Comment: not true. Track clearance is copper weight dependant. The standard KiCad shape is perfectly valid for 1oz but just violates for 3oz... so guess what, modify the footprint to make it compliant

Comment: This will not pass SMT DFM because is causes... wait for it... a bridge. Nor  can it be relied upon to make the connection with an application of paste + reflow. The only way you could reliably use this structure is to solder it, by hand, with a soldering iron. That’s extra cost and is mistake-prone. Way cheaper to use a zero ohm strap and set the pick-place as needed.

Comment: Thank you for this Sir. I will take it into consideration. Currently we have switched to a design with no solder bridges and just simple trace shorting, leaving unused terminals open - ended and covered with a tape to prevent shorting. Or of course for better safety we can have the 0 ohm resistors with pick and place option. The reason for considering solder bridges was to reduce stacking issues (as around 6 PCBs were stacked together for a planar winding) and we had to find a way to get the signal back to top PCB without using a wire (shorting holes basically). Hence the bridge.

Comment: there is nothing wrong with such jumpers for dev cards when you will be working on them. This is why there are two variants NO and NC because relying on reflow isn't a good idea. For instance a set of dev cards I m RFM has these on PSU output as NO so I can test and bridge when I am happy. For production.. these would be 0805 (and thus setting these to NC) resistors so retain the ability to open them. Please don't rule something out simple because of your specific use-cases